# Database Error When Adding/Editing Pages With Structure

Tags: ee2, error, structure, database

Whenever I attempt to add or edit a page in Structure, I get the following error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' listing_cid = 0, hidden = '' WHERE entry_id = 456' at line 1
>
> UPDATE exp_structure SET parent_id = , listing_cid = 0, hidden = '' WHERE entry_id = 456
>
> Filename: third_party/structure/mod.structure.php
>
> Line Number: 2993

It doesn't seem to matter what's on the page, how complicated it is, or how old it is.

The site's running on EE v2.11.7 and Structure v3.3.19. Attempting to use Structure's "Debug" mode did nothing.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? The only recent major change to the site was upgrading to a newer version of PHP. Hopefully that's not the culprit, because that was required to fix some compatibility issues with a different add-on.

Comment: Looks like Structure is expecting there to be a `parent_id`, but there is not, and since they expect it to be an integer, they are not quoting it, causing the SQL error when it's empty. I'd file this as a bug report with EE Harbor.